# Optimised a website for the search engines

Tags: html, optimization, search-engine, seo

How do you optimised a website for the search engines?

As far as I know, we put meta content and meta keywords on the web pages (but I am told that Google and all the main search engines have not used meta keywords at all for a few years now - is that correct??)

I read some tips online, said that we can put key words on the img alt attributes. So I wonder, if this is correct if I repeat the keywords in each img alt, for instance, I have three images on my home like this below,

```
<img src="1.jpg" alt="artist, science residencies, collaborations, genetic laboratories, moving image, sound, photography">

<img src="2.jpg" alt="artist, science residencies, collaborations, genetic laboratories, moving image, sound, photography">

<img src="3.jpg" alt="artist, science residencies, collaborations, genetic laboratories, moving image, sound, photography">
```

What else I should do to optimised a website apart from the meta content and the image alt atrribute?

Thanks.

**edit:**

thanks so much for the people who just helped me on this question but I don't understand wy some people marked/ voted this question as 'off-topic'? but never mind.

some answer suggests that - 'To really get a boost in SEO, you'll need to get some links to your page from other reputable pages on the internet.'

mind if I ask what it mean by 'you'll need to get some links to your page' - does it mean I should put my website address (http://mywebsite.com) more 'other reputable pages on the internet?

Then, what pages/ sites are considered as 'reputable'? Can I consider Twitter and Facebook as 'reputable'? If I can, then I will create a twitter page and a facebook fan page that contain my website addresses, so does it mean that I have 'some links' to my website pages?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of things you can do SEO wise. However nothing is guaranteed to work. You only can do your very best to make sure search engines can index your site.

I'll sum some things up:

Use good heading on your page (`<h1> <h2>` etc).

Add the h1 of your page to the title of the page.

Build a nice url. For example if you have a menu called Information with a submenu called About us. Build you url something like /information/about-us. And let the About us page have a h1 and title of About us.

You can use meta keywords on your page, however be carefull that you don't use too many of them. Say max. 20. And make sure your keywords are also in the content of the page. And make sure they are relevant.

Add a breadcrumb path to your pages.

Create a HTML sitemap.

Create a XML sitemap and place this in the root of your website and call it sitemap.xml

Don't put keywords in alt texts of images. Instead use to alt text to place a description of the image (e.g. what it represents).

Don't use images for texts (I f you need custom fonts use @font-face instead).

Don't have more URL pointing to the same pages.

Place important keywords in the content of the page.

If pages are getting a different url do a 301 redirect to the new url from the ´old´ url to keep the page ranking.

There are more things you can do, however I think you can start working on this for now :)

Comment: thanks for much for listing this! can I ask - what is 'a breadcrumb path'? thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation)#Websites

Comment: Really helpful and precise information.Thanks @PeeHaa

Answer (score 4):

**Do not** put keywords in your alt tags. How would you feel if you were using a screen reader and every time you got to an image it started screaming "**artist, science residencies, collaborations, genetic laboratories, moving image, sound, photography**"

SEO isn't hard.

- Up to date page content that is updated often
- A clear title that should match your h1 tag
- Clean markup using words that match your title and h1. (meaning your content should have to do with what you've titled it).
- Reputable content that people will link to.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the title you mentioned here does it refer to the html title tag <title>my website title</title> ? thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, meta keywords are kind of dead in the water, due to abuse. I understand meta description doesn't do much either as far as ranking...but a good description can entice searchers to actually choose your page if it appears in the rankings.

Focus on building a semantically beautiful web page: the Title gives a succinct, accurate description of what the page is about, the page is built with clear structure (good use of h1 and h2 tags, for instance), and the content actually has content.

But that's just on-page optimization. To really get a boost in SEO, you'll need to get some links to your page from other reputable pages on the internet.

There's a nice primer at [SEOmoz](http://guides.seomoz.org/beginners-guide-to-search-engine-optimization).

Comment: thanks for this. how is considered as 'good use of h1 and h2 tags'?

Comment: Best to think of it like an outline for a formal paper. So an h1 of "philosophers" might be followed by h2's of Pre-socratics and Enlightenment and Post-Modern. Wikipedia articles typically do a great job of this.

Comment: got it! thank you very much. mind if i ask one more thing - what do you mean by 'you'll need to get some links to your page' - do you mean I should put my website address (http://mywebsite.com) more 'other reputable pages on the internet' - what pages/ sites are considered as 'reputable'? Can I consider Twitter and Facebook as 'reputable'? If I can, then I will create a twitter page and facebook fan page that contain my website address, so does it mean that I have some links to my website pages?

Answer (score 0):

On-site SEO is the easy part, including a navigation hierarchy that search engines understand, sensible use of h1, h2, etc. and HTML tags in general, and targeting single webpages to deliver answers to specific questions.

But on-site SEO has more to do with making your website search-engine readable. It doesn't have much of an impact on actual rankings granted that you have the basics down and you aren't negatively impacting your rankings by appearing spammy.

Actually climbing the search engine results mostly has to do with other websites pointing back to your website. That's the basic concept of how search engines know how trustworthy and relevant your website is. To learn more about this, look up the general concept of getting "backlinks".